# How big data can we transfer between iPhone applications

Tags: iphone

I want to use "Custom URL Scheme" to transfer data from application to other application in iPhone.
Can I ask: How big data can we transfer from app to app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple URL Scheme Usage:  yourSchemeName://stringurl.........

Apple application need use `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`  to handle url data. So I think your question may be equal to  the maximum length of a URL.

Safari (Browser)
**At least 80,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 80,000 characters.**

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Comment: A big URL size is required for the canvas components, I guess :) If you right-click one of them and go to View Image, check out the URL -- the entire image is encoded in there as base 64!

Answer (score 4):

Your data size won't be limited if you use UIPasteboard instead.  This article details how to store your app's data into a named pasteboard, then pass the name of the pasteboard to another app using a custom URL scheme:

http://www.zacwhite.com/blog/2009/10/15/getting-user-data-from-a-lite-to-a-paid-app/

Answer (score 2):

I know one upper bound is 2^32 - 1 bytes, because that's the maximum length of a NSString on the iPhone, and NSURL can be converted to NSStrings.  But that may not be the lowest upper bound.